# where can I download Microsoft Script Editor standalone?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, debugging

I want debug my script for IE6. Now use Microsoft Script Debugger, but it not handy. I debug in virtual machine and not have office.

Help please! Where can I download Microsoft Script Editor **standalone**?

Comment: If you have MS Office then run MSD can via %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\MSE7.EXE (OFFICE12 or OFFICE11 etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use Visual Studio for debugging. Just download Visual Studio Express and check these articles:

http://berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/
http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-techniques-in-ie-6/

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of the modern office versions, MSE?.EXE does not seem to exist anymore. Even visual studio express is too big and bloated to use for light scripting work.

No, the only standalone vbscripting app that's light, that supports intellisense, and that has an object browser is vbsedit, by adersoft. Unfortunately, it's not free, is limited to 4 machines per license, and is so protected that it virtually cannot be made portable.

PsPad is really the only solution at the current moment, but it does not have intellisense, nor does it have an object browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's not available standalone, you have to install Office 2003. You are not required to install entire office, just select MSE in advanced settings.

Another option is to use Visual Studio. You can install VS itself or its remote debugger and debug from another machine

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx